# Create a Google Load Balancer with fixed IP to Istio Ingress Gateway in GKE

Tags: load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-dns

I Have a Google GKE with 2 nodes and Istio installed.

It created automatically 2 load balancers with ephemeral IPs. I use one of them in CloudDNS (HTTPS) to redirect DNS to one of the ingress-gateways.

When I need to recreate the cluster there will be another Istio with another ips. Then, I have to change the ip in cloudDNS. It takes some minutes to this change to take effect.

I have to eliminate these minutes. For that we want to create a load balancer with a fixed IP. This ip will be fixed in CloudDNS. This way, when I need to recreate the cluster I will change load balancer to point to the new cluster istio ingress gateway. The changes wil take effect immediately.

Then, my question is: How can I create a load balancer with a fixed IP to my Istio ingress gateways?

I tried several combinations of TCP load balancer/HTTPS Load Balancer with a fixed IP pointing to the LB created to istio-ingressgateways but when I put the Fixed IP in Cloud DNS it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible at the moment, I found this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/131862841) where is mention something about your issue.